# why does dhclient-script up the interface by itself?

Tags: networking, dhcp, client

I found out that even an interface is down, isc-dhclient can still request an ip for it, as in dhclient-script it will do :

```
ip link set dev ${interface} up
```

so that no matter that interface is up or down, dhclient will still up it and send socket.

My question is, what is that for? In my opinion, dhclient shall just log an error if the interface is shut down and go sleep or even kill itself. So for what reason isc-dhclient do that, for just convenience, or there is a careful considered reason which is now beyond my mind?

Answer (score 0):

`dhclient` is written to acquire an IP address via DHCP. This requires `dhclient` to put a DHCP request packet on the network, and receive a DHCP reply from a DHCP server on the network.

`dhclient` cannot do its job if all interfaces are down.

Comment: What I'm concerning is, the script is doing this ultra vires. As I mentioned, I think dhclient shall not work while it is asked for requesting ip but the interface is shut down, thus I removed that `ip link` command form `/sbin/dhclient-script` and so far it works as I expected: it will log error because it cannot send out socket. But I'm still worrying that maybe in some unknown situation things will go wrong.